# Differences between JSON response with Safari and Safari Mobile

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, codeigniter, jquery-mobile

I noticing some strange behavior between different browsers with a JSON response. The browser i'm having the issue with is Safari Mobile, specifically the iOS simulator.

I'm using Codeigniter and am returning a partial view. In all browsers (except Safari Mobile) my JSON response returns the following:

```
response.Html = 
    "<li>...</li>
     <li>...</li>
     <li>...</li>
     <li>...</li>
     <li>...</li>
     <li>...</li>"
```

This is exactly what I want - I expect 6 list items and I inject this into the page. But in Safari Mobile for some reason my response contains an array of 5 objects - these objects contain some of the data that should be used to populate the partial view:

```
response: Array[5]
     0: Object
     1: Object
     2: Object
     3: Object
     4: Object
     length: 5
```

The AJAX call for this looks like:

```
function getRandomMovies () {
    $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg("a", "Fetching random movies");
    $.ajax({
        url: "random/get_random_movies",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        cache: false,
        success: function (response) {
            $('#random-gallery').html(response.html);
            initPhotoSwipe();
            $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
            alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
        }  
    });
}
```

In the controller method for the AJAX call I have the following which should, and does in most browsers, return the HTML.

```
public function get_random_movies(){
        $movies = $this->random_model->get_random_movies();

        $data['results'] = $movies;
        $response['html'] = $this->load->view('partials/_random_movie_multiple', $data, true);

        echo json_encode($response);
    }
```

You'll have to forgive me for pasting all these code blocks but I believe they are all necessary to properly debug the issue. Any help on this would be appreciated, as I've spent a huge amount of time on trying to debug this problem, but to no avail.

**EDIT 1:**

**_random_movie_multiple.php**

```
foreach ($results as $result) {

    echo '<li><a data-ajax="false" rel="external" data-href="search/movie/'.url_title($result->title, "-", true).'/'.$result->id.'" data-caption="'.$result->title.' ('.$result->release_year.')" href="'.$result->img284.'"><img src="'.$result->img88.'"/></a></li>';

}
```

Comment: Version of Safari being used on iOS? Also `dataType: json` is not needed, as you're not actually sending any json to the server in that ajax request.

Comment: It appears to be 6.0 Mobile

Comment: I would very much like to see the output of the object from a browser that is *correctly* outputing your JSON.

Comment: The first code block above contains the correctly outputted JSON - response.Html = ... These lists items are correct and I inject them into the DOM

Comment: @Ohgodwhy `dataType : "json"` refers to what you expect in response from the server, not what you're sending the server with the request. It might be helpful to post the JSON you're parsing, or at least the chunk you're attempting to access.

Comment: @Jasper yea. Copy + pasta'd the wrong string. I meant the `contentType` string.

Comment: @Jasper I don't know if this is what you mean my the "JSON I'm parsing" but I've updated the original post with the partial view that I "should" be returning in the response